# how do you reverse the data given from a REST API response?

Tags: cumulocity

I'm trying to read measurement data, and I get a large amount of data back.  I can narrow down the items per page and get the last page, but is there a way to reverse the data so I get the most recent measurement POST?

For example, I to a:

```
GET: {{url}}/measurement/measurements?dateTo={{dateTo}}&dateFrom={{dateFrom}}&source={{deviceId}}
```

And I get get 100's of pages back, the list beginning from the first measurement.  I want the last measurement first.

Comment: It's the server's job to decide what the response looks like. What is the server? Do you have any control over that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, add revert=True

i.e.:
{{url}}/measurement/measurements?dateTo={{dateTo}}&dateFrom={{dateFrom}}&source={{deviceId}}&currentPage=1&pageSize=200&revert=True